# assertThrows multiple exceptions

Tags: java, exception, mockito, juniper

Can anyone tell me how to use assertThrows with several exceptions?

for ex, here is a class:

```
 protected void checkViolation(Set<ConstraintViolation<EcritureComptable>> vViolations) throws FunctionalException {
    if (!vViolations.isEmpty()) {
        throw new FunctionalException("L'écriture comptable ne respecte pas les règles de gestion.",
                                      new ConstraintViolationException(
                                          "L'écriture comptable ne respecte pas les contraintes de validation",
                                          vViolations));
    }
}
```

and my testing method:

```
 @Test
void checkViolation(){
    comptabiliteManager = spy(ComptabiliteManagerImpl.class);
    when(vViolations.isEmpty()).thenReturn(false);

    assertThrows(  ConstraintViolationException.class, () ->comptabiliteManager.checkViolation(vViolations), "a string should be provided!");
}
```

I would like to match the method and throw **ConstraintViolationException** and **FunctionalException** altogether

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single exception is thrown, and it's of type `FunctionalException`. The `cause` of this `FunctionalException` is a `ConstraintViolationException`.

Assuming `assertThrows` is the [JUnit 5 method](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows(java.lang.Class,org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable,java.lang.String)), it returns the thrown exception. So you can simply get its cause and add additional checks on this cause.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that ConstraintViolationException will be the root cause of FunctionalException. In this case to check that thrown exception has desired cause you can do something like

```
Executable executable = () -> comptabiliteManager.checkViolation(vViolations);

Exception exception = assertThrows(FunctionalException.class, executable);

assertTrue(exception.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException);
```

Another maybe more clean solution would be to use [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) and its API.

```
Throwable throwable = catchThrowable(() -> comptabiliteManager.checkViolation(vViolations));

assertThat(throwable).isInstanceOf(FunctionalException.class)
            .hasCauseInstanceOf(ConstraintViolationException.class);
```

You would have to import methods from Assertions class from AssertJ :

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.catchThrowable;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
```

I encourage you to look at this API because it has many fluent methods.